# Flutter Build repeatedly fails

Tags: gradle, flutter

Things were running quite smooth till recently for no apparent reason, **no new projects are running**. The older projects, however, are still running.

I have been trying to **run Flutter projects on my device or on an emulator but it repeatedly fails**. I have so far done a lot of things what many people have said in many forums but nothing seems to give any solution.

**So far, I have uninstalled and reinstalled**

- Android Studio,
- Flutter,
- Android SDK,
- AVDs and
- even tried to run on Visual Studio Code.

The result is the same. I.m pulling my hair out for the past 3 days and I hope somebody can be kind enough to help me... PLEASE!!!

```
arun@computer:flutterapp$ flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on ASUS Z01RD in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                              1.6s
Resolving dependencies...                                           2.7s
e: /Users/arunseshan/Work/AppDev/Flutter/flutterapp/android/app/src/main/kotlin/in/xtnds/flutterapp/MainActivity.kt: (1, 9): Package name must be a '.'-separated identifier list

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                

* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.                    
> Compilation error. See log for more details                           

* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              

BUILD FAILED in 15s                                                     
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        15.8s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Even the most *basic and default* flutter projects fail to compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the answer may seem weird but it actually works, I've tried it a couple of times so I think I can prove it.

until now, I have been able to use my domain `xtnds.in` in Android studio and there has been no problems whatsoever.

Recently something updated I guess and I think gradle is no longer accepting 2 character domain extensions

I don't truly know if that's the case but I wish some of the developers can look into it. It's a crazy strange problem and it gives no solid explanation for the problems it causes.

Answer (score 0):

Open your `MainActivity.kt` file, and check if your package name is in following format:

```
package: com.example.packagename
```

Comment: yes it is it says the following 

`package in.xtnds.flutterapp`

Comment: Open this file as separate module and see where exact the error is.

Comment: Package directive doesn't match file location

Comment: You edited question and added `Even the most basic and default flutter projects fail to compile`, I think you should reinstall flutter/dart. Or you may create a new issue on Github.

Comment: I've already done that, I have even reinstalled Android Studio and run several new projects on VS Code. I know that changing editors wont help but I was just doing it cos I could find no explanations for the error

Comment: Ok, in a new project, I changed my package name and it worked

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it, you can also write it down as answer.